# Rails Authentication Gem That Uses MongoDB As Default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, mongodb

I know that Devise can do this but I am not a big fan of devise because customization is very hard with Devise (I usually use AuthLogic). I want to use MongoDB as my main database I am just wondering if there is a gem already out there that uses MongoDB as its default storage. I have tried googling this but the most likely solution is a customized version of Devise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Nunemaker put together a pretty basic one here:
https://gist.github.com/147427